# How to have overlapping under-braces and over-braces

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I am trying to typeset an equation that has overlapping over and under braces as per the image below:

[image]

I have managed to typeset it using a sort of a hack, by typing the equation twice, once using `\phantom` commands and then raising it. Is there an easier way, perhaps a macro? MWE for the image above is shown below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[a+b+\overbrace{c+d+e+f+g}^{x}+h+i+k+l=e^2\]
\vspace{-35pt}
\[\phantom{+b+c+d+}\underbrace{\phantom{e+f+g+h+i}}_{y}\phantom{+k+=e^2}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get an underbrace and an overbrace to partially overlap in an equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297/how-can-i-get-an-underbrace-and-an-overbrace-to-partially-overlap-in-an-equation)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  a+b+\rlap{$\overbrace{\phantom{c+d+e+f+g}}^x$}c+d
     +\underbrace{e+f+g+h+i}_y +k+l=e^2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is better.

Comment: Nice solution. I think there should be a `{}` before `+k` to fix the spacing though.

Comment: It should be `+\>k` to get the right spacing for binary operators.

Comment: `\mathrel{+}` should do the trick

Comment: @Herbert: With `\mathrel`, the spaces are slightly too large.

Comment: @TH.: With `{}+k`, the space between the `i` and the `+` is too large, I don't exactly know why.

Answer (score 9):

In Herbert's *Mathmode* 63.2 Overlapping braces, he uses a similar method with `align`, `\hphantom` and `\\[-11pt]`.

I think it is better to use LaTeX's `\ooalign`:

```
\[
\ooalign{
  $a+b+\overbrace{c+d+e+f+g}^{x}+h+i+k+l=e^2$\cr
  $\phantom{a+b+c+d+{}} {\underbrace{\phantom{e+f+g+h+i}}_{y}} $\cr
}
\]
```

Note: `\ooalign` is defined in LaTeX kernel, and is used in definition of some special text accents and math symbols. It is defined with primitive `\halign`. Similar approach is widely used in LaTeX kernel to define overlapping symbols — like `\angle`, `\cong`, `\notin`, `\overrightarrow` and `\overbrace`, etc.

Comment: I think it should read: "Plain's `\ooalign`"

Comment: @morbusg: There're some macros defined both in LaTeX and Plain TeX format. Although Plain TeX is earlier, it is still a LaTeX command, right?

Comment: Well, sure, if you want to diss Plain.

Comment: @morsburg @Leo Liu, thanks. I looked this one up and is in the `ltxplain.dtx`, where all the Plain commands live in LaTeX. Nice solution.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the definitions of the `\overbrace` and `\underbrace` macros reveals that the are using `\ialign` which `\halign` with a zero `\tabskip` and empty `\everycr`.

So the braces are on there own "table rows". It is possible to define a macro which does take three arguments: the first part only under the overbrace, the middle part between both and the last part only over the underbrace. Then place this into a similar `\ialign` structure with three cells and three rows. The braces are then put into the plainTeX equivalent of `\multicolumn{2}` (`\span\omit` as I understand it).

However, the super- and subscript doesn't work as normal and must be read manual and placed at the correct positions. Getting them to the correct vertical position was the most difficult thing to get right.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\iffalse
% The definitions of the existing macros for study:

\overbrace:
macro:#1->\mathop {\vbox {\m@th \ialign {##\crcr 
\noalign {\kern 3\p@ }\downbracefill \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@ \nointerlineskip }$\hfil \displaystyle {#1}\hfil $\crcr 
}}}\limits 

\underbrace:
macro:#1->\mathop {\vtop {\m@th \ialign {##\crcr 
$\hfil \displaystyle {#1}\hfil $\crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@ \nointerlineskip }\upbracefill \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@ }%
}}}\limits 

\fi

\makeatletter
\def\overunderbrace#1#2#3{%
    \begingroup
    \let\overunderbrace@sup\empty
    \let\overunderbrace@sub\empty
    \@ifnextchar^%
        {\@overunderbracesup{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@ifnextchar_%
            {\@overunderbracesub{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
            {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        }%
}

\def\@overunderbracesup#1#2#3^#4{%
    \def\overunderbrace@sup{#4}%
    \@ifnextchar_%
        {\@overunderbracesub{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\@overunderbracesub#1#2#3_#4{%
    \def\overunderbrace@sub{#4}%
    \@ifnextchar^%
        {\@overunderbracesup{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\@overunderbrace#1#2#3{%
\mathop {\vcenter {\m@th \ialign {##&##&##\crcr
    \noalign {\kern 3\p@}%
    \span\omit\hfil\hbox{\vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox{\vbox{\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle\overunderbrace@sup$}\vspace{0pt}}}}}\hfil
    &%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 5\p@\nointerlineskip}%
    \span\omit\downbracefill&%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#1}\hfil $&%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#2}\hfil $&%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#3}\hfil $%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
      & \span\omit  \upbracefill
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 5\p@\nointerlineskip}%
    &\span\omit\hfil\hbox{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox{\vbox{\vspace{0pt}\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle\overunderbrace@sub$}}}\vss}}\hfil
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@ }%
}}}%
    \endgroup
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

% The extra `\mathord{}` is used to get the spacing right, otherwise
% the +'s before f and h think they are signs not operators. 
% This is content specific and can't be added to the \overunderbracemacro.
\[
a+b+\overunderbrace{c+d+\mathord{}}{e+f+g}{\mathord{}+h+i}^{x}_{y} =e^2
\]

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

Use the package [`oubraces`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/oubraces/oubraces.pdf), it provides the command `\overunderbraces{upper_braces}{main_formula}{lower_braces}`.

In the `main_formula` use the token `&` to split the formula in blocks pointing where *start* and *end* the **braces**; in the other arguments use `\br{n}{label}` where `n` is the number of *blocks* spanned by the brace and separate them with `&`.

For this example the code looks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{oubraces}
\begin{document}
\[ x=\overunderbraces{&\br{2}{x}}% upper brace
{a+b+&c+d+&e+f+g&+h+i}% main formula
{&&\br{2}{y}}=e^2 % lower brace 
\]
\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could also use this solution, which makes use of the package [underoverlap](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/underoverlap/underoverlap.pdf)

```
\usepackage{underoverlap}

\[\UOLunderbrace{w \leq}[p]_{=q} \UOLunderbrace{\leq v}_{=q}\]

\[ a + b + \UOLoverbrace{c+d+}[e+f+g]^x \UOLunderbrace{+h+i}_y + k + l = e^2 \]
```

[image]

It also works with two Underbraces (or two Overbraces) instead of one underbrace followed by an overbrace, although the result looks a little bit undesirable in that case.