# (How) can I manually specify the axis of a (horizontal) box in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`underoverlap`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/underoverlap)

I've been using the `\overunderbrace` macro provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12968/14886). It works fine for simple examples, but since the original definition uses `\vcenter`, vertical alignment is not correct when the axis of the 'content' is not aligned to its vertical center. For example, to get proper alignment in the following formula, I had to do some manual tweaking with `\raisebox`. Not ideal.

[image]

I'm trying to perfect the macro; perhaps write a small package. (There are several extensions possible, e.g., `\underoverbrace`, custom vertical spacing, custom brace-command (`\underoverline`), etc.)

**Question:** Rather than 'naively' using `\vcenter`, is there a way to raise/lower the whole structure the exact amount needed to align its axis with the axis of the 'content' (which is a row in a `\halign`)?

Several possible solutions come to mind:

- The simplest (for me) would be to add two optional arguments to the macro for the content before and after the bracing. I could then put them in the 'content row'. But I'd rather not have to.
- If I have to, I can probably measure the segments and calculate the correct amount to raise/lower.

I'm just hoping there's a simpler solution I'm not yet aware of.

---

**Edit:** Here's a simple MWE of the misalignment, based on the example of the original answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\overunderbrace#1#2#3{%
    \begingroup
    \let\overunderbrace@sup\empty
    \let\overunderbrace@sub\empty
    \@ifnextchar^%
        {\@overunderbracesup{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@ifnextchar_%
            {\@overunderbracesub{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
            {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        }%
}

\def\@overunderbracesup#1#2#3^#4{%
    \def\overunderbrace@sup{#4}%
    \@ifnextchar_%
        {\@overunderbracesub{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\@overunderbracesub#1#2#3_#4{%
    \def\overunderbrace@sub{#4}%
    \@ifnextchar^%
        {\@overunderbracesup{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\@overunderbrace#1#2#3{%
\mathop {\vcenter {\m@th \ialign {##&##&##\crcr
    \noalign {\kern 3\p@}%
    \span\omit\hfil\hbox{\vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox{\vbox{\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle\overunderbrace@sup$}\vspace{0pt}}}}}\hfil
    &%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 5\p@\nointerlineskip}%
    \span\omit\downbracefill&%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#1}\hfil $&%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#2}\hfil $&%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#3}\hfil $%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
      & \span\omit  \upbracefill
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 5\p@\nointerlineskip}%
    &\span\omit\hfil\hbox{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox{\vbox{\vspace{0pt}\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle\overunderbrace@sub$}}}\vss}}\hfil
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@ }%
}}}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    $$
        a+b+
        \overunderbrace
            {c+\mathord{\mathop{\Sigma}_d} + \mathord{}}
            {e+f+g}
            {\mathord{}+h+i}^{x}_{y}
        = e^2
    $$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Care to give a small MWE for the misaligned text?

Comment: Here you go. It's based on the original example. Note the `\Sigma` subscript sticking out, which is the cause of the misalignment.

Comment: holy cow that is some sophisticated TeX

Comment: It's not so bad if you understand the basics. (It never is.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to centre it: just take off the underbrace so the baseline of the construct is the baseline of the base, then rebuild it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\overunderbrace#1#2#3{%
    \begingroup
    \let\overunderbrace@sup\empty
    \let\overunderbrace@sub\empty
    \@ifnextchar^%
        {\@overunderbracesup{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@ifnextchar_%
            {\@overunderbracesub{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
            {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        }%
}

\def\@overunderbracesup#1#2#3^#4{%
    \def\overunderbrace@sup{#4}%
    \@ifnextchar_%
        {\@overunderbracesub{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\@overunderbracesub#1#2#3_#4{%
    \def\overunderbrace@sub{#4}%
    \@ifnextchar^%
        {\@overunderbracesup{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
        {\@overunderbrace{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\def\@overunderbrace#1#2#3{%
\mathop {\setbox\z@\vbox{\m@th \ialign {##&##&##\crcr
    \noalign {\kern 3\p@}%
    \span\omit\hfil\hbox{\vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox{\vbox{\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle\overunderbrace@sup$}\vspace{0pt}}}}}\hfil
    &%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 5\p@\nointerlineskip}%
    \span\omit\downbracefill&%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#1}\hfil $&%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#2}\hfil $&%
        $\hfil \displaystyle {#3}\hfil $%
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
      & \span\omit  \upbracefill
    \crcr \noalign {\kern 5\p@\nointerlineskip}%
    &\span\omit\hfil\hbox{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox{\vbox{\vspace{0pt}\hbox{$\m@th\scriptstyle\overunderbrace@sub$}}}\vss}}\hfil
    \crcr %\noalign {\kern 3\p@ }%
}%
\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox
\unkern
\global\setbox\thr@@\lastbox
\unkern
}%
\vtop{\box\z@\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip\box\thr@@\kern5\p@\nointerlineskip\box\@ne\kern3\p@}%
}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    $$
        a+b+
        \overunderbrace
            {c+\mathord{\mathop{\Sigma}_d} + \mathord{}}
            {e+f+g}
            {\mathord{}+h+i}^{x}_{y}
        = e^2
    $$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool. :-) Thanks! I knew about `\vtop`, but I didn't know about 'unboxing' yet.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take, based on [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12969) to the question you cited. For simplicity I defined an `\overunderbrace` with *five* arguments (the last two being the things to be put over / under the braces), but it could also be done as in your sample code.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*\overunderbrace[5]{%
  \mathrlap{\overbrace{\phantom{#1#2}}^{\mathclap{#4}}}%
  #1\mathord{\underbrace{#2#3}_{\mathclap{#5}}}%
  }
\begin{document}
\[
  a+b+\overunderbrace{c+\mathord{\mathop{\Sigma}_d}+}{e+f+g}{+h+i}{x}{y}+k+l=e^2
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm... That's quite elegant. Short code, and the underbrace isn't hindered by the `\Sigma_d`. Don't know how I missed Herbert's answer on my original pass through that question.

Comment: This solution is probably better for the `\underoverbrace` problem, but I gotta give the green tick to David, who more directly answered my question.

Comment: @mhelvens: The choice which answer to give to green tick is completely up to you `:-)`

Comment: I know. :-p I just wanted to reiterate that I prefer your solution, at least for the specific problem I used as an example.