# equivalent of showframe on generic boxes (for debugging)

Tags: debugging

I have done a lot of searching but cannot figure out how to visualized the box that a piece of content falls into without shifting the content. How do *you* debug?

Note: [How can I visualize boxes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/how-can-i-visualize-boxes) could be a good question if it had answers that worked without lua. But, also that OP is specifically looking to outline **all boxes** which I am not. If I were able to get that to work, I'd probably have a whole new problem interpreting what I see.

Comment: I did look at that answer, but it was not useful. There's not a way to say "can I get more answers to this" so I have to ask the question differently.

Comment: The way would be to add a comment at the other question. And if you ask a new question at please post a link to the other one and explain what makes your question different … maybe you like to edit your question and add some more information ;-)

Comment: Done. Thanks @Tobi. I didn't link earlier because it was a hassle as I was posting via mobile app.

Comment: Your welcome, and thanks for clarification. I’m not aware of other solutions with pure (La)TeX. But maybe you could explain a bit mor in detail what exactly you want to debug, at least I didn’t understand it yet – I guess … maybe you also add an MWE illustrating a thing you want to debug.

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to understand. Can you add more detail as to what you want and a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)?

Answer (score 3):

A simple `\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}` helps if you use `\fbox`. I sometimes use something similar to

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\fbox{test1}}}test2
\end{document}
```

[image]

As one can see, no issues with shifted text, `test1` is exactly below `test2`. In case you want a more general approach, with probably other drawbacks, you can use something similar to [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439178/97512), an answer by Circumscribe to help debugging in math mode.

Comment: I had to add a `\noindent` inside the fbox, but after that it put a box around it without shifting anything. This is very helpful. Am I don't something that makes it want to indent? Can I fix that? (That's probably the biggest reason I'm having to debug.)

Comment: I'd still like to find a solution to visualize an existing box rather than  create a new one. Creating a new one can be error prone (as demonstrated).

Comment: @BrunoBronosky I assume you don't use Texlive then? The provided code produces exactly the picture I posted for me, running Texlive (on Linux, though). You can, of course, create custom commands to get rid of that need (if it's indeed needed), like `\newcommand{\myfbox}[1]{\fbox{\noindent#1}}`. You could also store and restore the previous used `\fboxsep` if you want to use `\fbox` in your main document as well.