# Overlapping over/underbrace

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I wanted to do something like this: [How to have overlapping under-braces and over-braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12963/how-to-have-overlapping-under-braces-and-over-braces)

The example given is really great, so I tried it on my own: what I was hoping to achieve is to represent a contribution from four fields to Wick theorem by clipping pair of fields, so I tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \overbracket{\phi (x_1) \quad \phi (x_2)} \quad \overbracket{\phi (x_3) \quad \phi (x_4)} \\
        \rlap{$\overbracket{\phantom{\phi (x_1) \quad \phi(x_2) \quad \phi (x_3)}}$} \phi(x_1) \quad
        \underbracket{\phi (x_2) \quad \phi (x_3) \quad \phi (x_4)} \\
        \overbracket{\phi (x_1) \quad \underbracket{\phi (x_2) \quad \phi (x_3)} \quad \phi (x_5)}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Almost, but not quite! The under/overbrackets are starting and ending on the wrong position, I would rather stress the point (`x_1`, ...), where the bracket starts or ends. So I tried modifying it like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \phi (x\!\!\overbracket{\,_{1}) \quad \phi (x\!}{\,}_{\!2}) \quad \phi (x\!\overbracket{_3) \quad \phi (x\!}{\,}_{\!4}) \\
        \rlap{$\phi (x\!\!\overbracket{\phantom{\,_1) \quad \phi(x_2) \quad \phi (x}}_3)$} \phi(x_1) \quad
        \phi (x\!\!\underbracket{\,_2) \quad \phi (x_3) \quad \phi (x\!}{\,}_{\!4}) \\
        \phi (x\!\!\overbracket{\,_1) \quad \phi (x\!\!\underbracket{\,_2) \quad \phi (x\!}{\,}_{\!3}) \quad \phi (x\!}{\,}_{\!4})
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is, in fact, very ugly code, but it works for the first and last case - because there are no interlapping clips. What is worse than ugly code, is that this is not working for the middle case (interlapping clip `x1 - x3` and `x2 - x4`), when number 3 is positioned below the first overbracket (right under `x_2`, where the second clip starts), the right parenthesis is duplicated and also, if you watch carefully, the `\phi (x` is somewhat bold, so it's duplicated and slightly displaced too. How can I achieve the interlapping clips effect with exact positioning over x's without these issues?

Thank you.

P.S.: I'm using pdflatex in TeXworks

Comment: Related: [How to put a big bracket under different parts of a equation so that I could write e.g. a text specific to that part in the equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44834/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simpler to do it with `pst-node`: consider variables you want to link as `\rnodes`, and connect them with the `\ncbar` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \phi (\rnode{n1}{x_1}) \quad \phi (\rnode{n2}{x_2}) \quad\phi (\rnode{n3}{x_3}) \quad \phi (\rnode{n4}{x_4}) \\[1ex]
        \phi (\rnode{p1}{x_1}) \quad \phi(\rnode{p2}{x_2}) \quad \phi (\rnode{p3}{x_3}) \quad\phi(\rnode{p4}{x_4}) \\[2ex]
       \phi (\rnode{q1}{x_1}) \quad \phi (\rnode{q2}{x_2}) \quad \phi (\rnode{q3}{x_}3) \quad \phi (\rnode{q4}{x_4})
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\psset{nodesep=3pt, arm=5pt, angle=90, linejoin=1}
\ncbar{n1}{n2}\ncbar{n3}{n4}
\ncbar{p1}{p3}\ncbar[nodesep=2pt, angle=-90]{p2}{p4}
\ncbar{q1}{q4}\ncbar[nodesep=2pt, angle=-90]{q2}{q3}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really good and it also possesses the same logic I was hoping for to achieve! if nobody come with something better in 12 hours (I doubt it), I'll accept this, ok? Thank you.

Comment: P.S.: after loading \usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}, there is an error:
! Package auto-pst-pdf Error: 
    "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
    auto-pst-pdf will not work!
.

See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.134         Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
                                        %
? 

If I turn off auto-pst-pdf as suggested, the error occures with 'poscript' (latex doesnt recognize that).

Comment: Oh! yes. I forgot to mention it. To compile `pstricks` code with `pdflatex`, you have to launch it with the `--enable-write18` switch (under MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Alternatively, you can compile with `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: I don't have "MiKTeX" in the 'typeset' menu...I can't find those things you described in my TeXworks...and XeLaTeX has a problem with some 'non utf8 characters', even I have imported [slovak]{babel}.

Comment: What is your distribution?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you're asking, but "about texworks" said this: texworks is a simple environment for editing, typesetting and previewing tex documents. copyright 2007 - 2013, three names (are they important now?), blabla, version 0.4.5 r.1280 (official), distributed under GNU general public licence version 2 or (at your option) any later version. Look, I'm just a physicist, I'm not really a computer guy...I mean...I have windows 10. What is 'distribution'? :( (or do you mean generalized function? :)) I know you're trying to help and I'm really trying to understand what you mean...

Comment: I mean: do you use MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: I'd say Tex Live, because when I installed TeXworks, it also created folder TeXlive (with 5GB of content), but I don't remember if I ever dealt with this texlive thing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40362/discussion-between-bernard-and-user16320).

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by Bernard answer, just for exercise, below is solution based on TikZ picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,inner ysep=0pt,row sep=2ex]
{
\phi(x_1)   &   \phi(x_2)   &   \phi(x_3)   &   \phi(x_4)   \\
\phi(x_1)   &   \phi(x_2)   &   \phi(x_3)   &   \phi(x_4)   \\
\phi(x_1)   &   \phi(x_2)   &   \phi(x_3)   &   \phi(x_4)   \\
};
\draw[thick,transform canvas={xshift=0.3ex}]
    (m-1-1) |- ([yshift=+1mm] m-1-2.north) -- (m-1-2)
    (m-1-3) |- ([yshift=+1mm] m-1-4.north) -- (m-1-4)
    (m-2-1) |- ([yshift=+1mm] m-2-3.north) -- (m-2-3)
    (m-2-2) |- ([yshift=-1mm] m-2-4.south) -- (m-2-4)
    (m-3-1) |- ([yshift=+1mm] m-3-4.north) -- (m-3-4)
    (m-3-2) |- ([yshift=-1mm] m-3-3.south) -- (m-3-3)
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not much better. Notice the bolder phi in the second row. Also, subscript positioning doesn't match in the first and second row. Also phi's are not aligned at all.

Comment: In the firs version of my answer I try to show the way, how you can improve your code. However, result was unsatisfactory, so instead this, I rewrote answer with completely different approach. To my opinion with simple, concise and easy to understand code.

Comment: Thank you, this is also great! However, I accepted the other solution because it is somewhat concise, plus the guy helped me with shell escape, so everything works now. Thank you anyway!