# Underbracket and overbracket intersecting each other

Tags: formatting, mathtools, overbrace

I cannot seem to find a way to achieve the result I want which is best portrayed by this sketch diagram:

[image: x spanning two underbrackets]

This is because if I add an overbracket it is closed by the underbracket `}` before it gets to the second group of underbracket.

```latex
$w = 
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aaa...a}_{n}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aaa...a}_{m}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{bbb...b}_{n}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aaa...a}_{m}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{bbb...b}_{n}
$
```

## Solution:

As suggested in this post: [How to have overlapping under-braces and over-braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12963/how-to-have-overlapping-under-braces-and-over-braces)

[image: Solution]

```
$
w = 
    \rlap{\phantom{aaa}$\overbracket[0.75pt]{\phantom{aaaaa}}^x$}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aaa...a}_{n}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aaa...a}_{m}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{bbb...b}_{n}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aaa...a}_{m}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{bbb...b}_{n}
$\\
```

Note that the letters added in the phantom do not matter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does the posting [How to have overlapping under-braces and over-braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12963/5001) help?

Comment: Hi @Mico and thank you. Yes, that does help a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the posts from [Mico's link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12963/5001) are the best way to go, but here is an alternative that allows you to avoid typing the text twice: `tikzmark`. I actually do not think that this method is superior in this very case because

1. you have to load another package,
2. you need to insert a `\vphantom` to get the vertical space right as an `overlay` `tikzpicture` does not insert space, and
3. you need to give each `\tikzmarknode` a unique label.

However, it is an alternative, and as soon as you want a more fancy bracket (bent, dashed, whatever) this method is likely to continue to give you what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
Some text to test the vertical space.

$
w = \vphantom{\overbracket[0.75pt]{a}^{x}}% to fix the vertical space
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aa\tikzmarknode{a1}{a}\dots a}_{n}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{a\tikzmarknode{a2}{a}a\dots a}_{m}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{bbb\dots b}_{n}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aaa\dots a}_{m}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{bbb\dots b}_{n}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \draw[line width=0.75pt] (a1.north east) -- ++ (0,0.8ex)
      -| node[pos=0.25,above]{$x$} (a2.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
$

Some text to test the vertical space.
\[w = \vphantom{\overbracket[0.75pt]{a}^{x}}% to fix the vertical space
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aa\tikzmarknode{a3}{a}\dots a}_{n}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{a\tikzmarknode{a4}{a}a\dots a}_{m}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{bbb\dots b}_{n}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{aaa\dots a}_{m}
    \underbracket[0.75pt]{bbb\dots b}_{n}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \draw[line width=0.75pt] (a3.north east) -- ++ (0,0.8ex)
      -| node[pos=0.25,above]{$x$} (a4.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
Some text to test the vertical space.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that the way suggested by @Mico is tiddier, but this is also a good variation. Thank you for the help