# Diagram of a sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help me I have been looking for how to make a diagram similar to this image. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: the site works best if you ask a _tex_ question. Show the code you tried and if you get an error someone will debug. Also are those vertical lines, or 1s ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't know if the round braces are important to you. If square or curly braces would be acceptable, you could look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297/125871) or [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12963/125871).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

You can create a macro that draws the arcs above and below the vertical bars. If you want only one macro for both kind of arcs you need to change the axis locally, i.e. `y=#3 cm` in my example, where the argument `#3` can take only values 1/-1.

A complete solution could be:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\myarc}[3] % start, end, 1/-1 (up, down) 
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\l{int(#2-#1+1)} % label
  \draw[y=#3 cm,red] (#1-0.2,0.5) to[out=30*#3,in=150*#3] node[midway,yshift=#3*0.25cm] {$\l$} (#2+0.2,0.5) ;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
% vertical bars
\foreach\i in {1,...,16}
  \draw[thick] (\i,-0.5) --++ (0,1);
% top arcs
\myarc {2} {5}{1}
\myarc {6} {9}{1}
\myarc{11}{14}{1}
\myarc{15}{16}{1}
% bottom arcs
\myarc {3} {6}{-1}
\myarc {8}{11}{-1}
\myarc{13}{15}{-1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gracias por su valiosa ayuda, de echo el que estor intentando es este código,

\begin{eqnarray*}
X_m : 0, 1, \underbrace{ 1,  \overbrace{ 1,  }^{\textcolor{blue}{2|_{X_4}}}  }_{\textcolor{blue}{2|_{X_3}}} \overbrace{ 1, }^{\textcolor{blue}{2|_{X_4}}} \underbrace{ 1,  1,  }_{\textcolor{blue}{2|_{X_6}}}  \underbrace{ 1,  1, }_{\textcolor{blue}{2|_{X_{8}}}} 1, 1, ....
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Pero no logro que la llave superior de X_4 cubra a los dos números, sin afectar a las llaves inferiores.

Comment: @EnriqueTorresMiguel. Quizás mejor si planteas una nueva pregunta, pones ese código y explicas tu problema.