# Unwanted space in overlapping overgroup and undergroup

Tags: underbrace, mathabx

I am trying to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12969/28115) on [How to have overlapping under-braces and over-braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12963/28115) to overlapping overgroup/undergroup, but I seem to be getting unwanted extra space:

[image: overlapping undergroup overgroup]

Is there a way to get rid of the extra space between 2 and 3, or else to make the space more symmetrical (a little extra space between 2 and 3 and between 3 and 4 would be OK)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\rlap{$\undergroup{\phantom{123}}$}12\overgroup{345}   \\
\mathrlap{\undergroup{\phantom{123}}}12\overgroup{345}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The space is generated by the `\undergroup` size, as you can see by removing the `\phantom` command:
[image: \undergroup add space]

So you can smash both `\undergroup` and `\overgroup`, but with `\mathclap` to get them centered. Use this small hack to draw them a the good place:

```tex
\settowidth{\sometempdim}{123}        % get content width
\kern 0.5\sometempdim\relax           % move to the middle of the expression
\mathclap{\undergroup{\phantom{123}}} % typeset the \undergroup sign
\kern -0.5\sometempdim\relax          % go back
123                                   % typeset the expression
```

Define some dedicated commands for that:

```tex
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\phantomundergroup}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#1}
  \kern 0.5\@tempdima\relax
  \mathclap{\undergroup{\phantom{#1}}}
  \kern -0.5\@tempdima\relax
}
\newcommand*{\phantomovergroup}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#1}
  \kern 0.5\@tempdima\relax
  \mathclap{\overgroup{\phantom{#1}}}
  \kern -0.5\@tempdima\relax
}
\makeatletter
```

Here I used `\@tempdima`, which is already defined by LaTeX (and hopefully not used internally by `\mathclap`, `\overgroup` nor `\phantom`). But you can use any length if you defined it before. The `\makeatletter...\makeatother` are necessary to handle the `@` in `\@tempdima` name.

Full code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\phantomundergroup}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#1}
  \kern 0.5\@tempdima\relax
  \mathclap{\undergroup{\phantom{#1}}}
  \kern -0.5\@tempdima\relax
}
\newcommand*{\phantomovergroup}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#1}
  \kern 0.5\@tempdima\relax
  \mathclap{\overgroup{\phantom{#1}}}
  \kern -0.5\@tempdima\relax
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  12345\\
  \phantomundergroup{123}12
  \phantomovergroup{345}345
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: with phantomgroups]