# Space-efficient underbrace

Tags: underline, underbrace

[image]
How to obtain the above right image with Tex?
 
If too difficult, you may also present a solution with straight lines.
 
If you know a better alternative, then by all means present it.
 
The solution will be used in situations where the usual underbrace leads to look that is either crammed or yields large white-space gaps.
The following link may be useful for a solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25513/120150

Comment: You can, rather simply, with `pstricks`.

Comment: What you try so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This just copies the definition of `\underbrace` adding an extra argument to hold the text and then finally using the text rather than the central part of the brace.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\zzunderbrace#1#2{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   \zzupbracefill{#2}\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}

\def\zzupbracefill#1{$\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill
  \,\lower .1em\hbox{\scriptsize#1}\,%
  \leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$\zzunderbrace{A+B+C+D+E+F}{some text}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. And still works when I raise/lower the text with a \raisebox. Perhaps silly question: but do the 'zz' have a particular meaning?

Comment: @Bart no, just a hidden fingerprint for me:-) if you search this site for zz you may find several of my answers:-)

Comment: A few weeks later. I tried adapting your solution to mathtool's underbracket, unfortunately unsuccessful. If you/someone still reads this, could you post a solution for underbracket? Thanks in advance. N.B. I believe the '\makeatletter' in the above solution should be closed with a '\makeatother' instead of with a second '\makeatletter'