# End brace in the wrong location?

Tags: mathjax

I have the following TeX - embedded via MathJax - in an HTML file. The result is shown below but isn't what I expected to see. Instead, I would like to end the "github" brace before `.com`. How should this be written in order to properly terminate the environment?

```
 \(
{\underbrace
{\overbrace{chris}^{\text{me}}
{\underbrace{@\overbrace{chrisfinazzo.com}^{\text{website}}}_{\text{github}}}}_{\text{email}}
\text{}}
\)
```

[image]

Comment: Although MathJax look like TeX, it is really another hairy beast and then this question is off-topic in this site.  I guess that over-underbraces must be strictly nested, not partially overlapped, and therefore the least bad solution could be not include the `@`, i.e.,  `\underbrace{\overbrace{cris}^{me}@\overbrace{\underbrace{chrisfinazzo}_{github}.com}}_{email}`. However, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297/how-can-i-get-an-underbrace-and-an-overbrace-to-partially-overlap-in-an-equation

Comment: @Fran I'll see if that does it. I'm really trying to get out of the TeX system for most things as it's overkill for my current needs. The `@print` Media Type in HTML is more than capable at this point, but the typography controls are better in TeX, so that's what I tried first. 

By my count, I only have 3 documents that need to be converted, so it shouldn't take that long. This particular one is for the rare times I need business cards, so it required some special considerations.