How can show ratios with tikz arrows?
How can show the rations with arrows in the equation with tikz? As shown in the picture. Thank you in advance.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%5  Equation 1

    If $a: b,=2: 3, b: c=3:4$, and $c: a=4: 2$, then $a: b: c=2: 3: 4$,
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Equation 2

If $a: b=2: 3$, and $b: c=5: 4$ (note $3 \neq 5)$, then $a: b: c=(2 \times 5):(3 \times 5):(3 \times$ 4) $=10: 15: 12$. 

\end{document}


You may use the following template as your starting point:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]%
{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%5  Equation 1

    If $a : b = 2 : 3, b : c = 3 : 4$, and $c : a = 4 : 2$, then $a : b : c = 2 : 3 : 4$,
\[
    \begin{aligned}
      a : b = 2 : &~3&\\
      &&a : b : c = 2 : 3 : \tikznode{four1}4\\
      b : c = &~3 : \tikznode{four}4&
    \end{aligned}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,cyan,rounded corners,
                      >=stealth,shorten > =1pt,shorten <=1pt,thick]
  \draw[->] (four)-- +(0,-0.3) -| (four1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The macro \tikznode is taken from this post: Draw arrows from one part of a sentence to another


Actually, what you write as \tikznode originally comes from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316/86 and is the core of the tikzmark library, available on ctan.
